# Strange situation with QThread QT3

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

I creati a simple class which extends two classes QObject and QThread.

When I compile it with MOC compiler there is an error:

expected class-name before ‘{’ token

Class started with this code:

```
class QSmartecVideoAudio : public QObject, public QThread
 {
 Q_OBJECT
 ...
 };
```

I implement run method but it doesnot work.

I include qthread.h at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like an include issue. Try to add:

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QObject>
```

before your class definition.

Comment: I use Qt3, includeing headers looks like <qobject.h> and <qthread.h>.. There no QThread or QObject files in /include/ dirrectory.

Comment: And I have already included both <qobject.h> and <qthread.h> headers in my code...

Comment: Maybe they are they defined in a namespace, then?

Comment: Problem was that Qt3 lib was compiled without thread supporting

Answer (score 1):

QThread inherits QObject already, so you must not inherit from QObject.

try:

```
class QSmartecVideoAudio : public QThread
{
   Q_OBJECT
   ...
};
```